# Showing certain tags in editor without executing them

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to add code as plain text in the editor.

For example when I type in `<script>alert('test');</script>` I want it to show the exact same way (plain text) and not executing it.

Right now, I've tried several config settings but it makes the script tags not show in the editor.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Several things that I've tried:
`config.protectedSource.push(/<script>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi);`

`config.allowedContent = true;`

```
config.allowedContent = {
        script: true,
        $1: {
            // This will set the default set of elements
            elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
            attributes: true,
            styles: true,
            classes: true
        }
    };
```

Comment: If you want display javascript as code snippet, you need to convert your < and > characters to HTML entities like so: &lt;script&gt;alert('test');&lt;/script&gt;

Comment: Sadly I've tried this already in the script that saves the content to the database and as well as the place where it shows the content, sadly this didn't really helped...

Comment: By just normally posting my form it says it as this in the database: `<p>&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;test&#39;);&lt;/script&gt;</p>` so it's already like that, yet CKEditor doesnt show it in the editor

Comment: Maybe you have some wrong editor configuration? I tested it on official page and it seems to work fine: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full-all/samples/